# Cordova iOS In App Purchase crashing when loading product details

Tags: ios, cordova

I am using `cordova-plugin-purchase` (https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase) in a Cordova (Ionic 4) app, which works on Android no problems. When I try to test a purchase on iOS, the app crashes with unexplained message below.

The app is also unable to retrieve product details from the store. I mention that the app is not yet released and it's currently in TestFlight.

This is the output log via Xcode:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SKProduct localizedPrice]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x28191ca40'
```

This is how I try to get the product details (crashes with output above)

```
this.store.get("coin_pack_1");
```

And this is how I try to initiate a purchase (crashes with output above)

```
let productId = "coin_pack_1";
let iapOptions: IAPProductOptions = {
    id: productId,
    alias: productId,
    type: this.store.CONSUMABLE
};

this.store.register(iapOptions);
this.store.verbosity = this.store.DEBUG;

let product: IAPProduct = this.store.get(productId);

// register handlers

this.store.once(productId).approved((data: IAPProduct) => {
    // Fired when a purchase has been approved by the store
    console.log("approved, ", data);
    product.finish();
    resolve(true);
});
this.store.refresh();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now switched (forced) to WKWebView as UIWebView was not allowed anymore on App Store, which somehow solved the issue.

```
<preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
   <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
       <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
   </feature>
<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
```